# strictly diagonally dominant by rows matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I have a question about this exercises:
We suppose that  we have a matrix A with real eigenvalues $λ_1 > · · · > λ_n> 0$ and strictly
diagonally dominant by rows such that:
$$ \gamma  \lvert a_{ii}\lvert\geq \sum _{j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus \{i\}} \lvert a_{ij}\lvert$$
We want to prove that :
$$\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_n}\leq\frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma}\cdot\frac{\max_{i}a_{ii}}{\min_{j}a_{jj}}$$
Is there anyway we can prove it using some properties of Rayleigh quotient?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Provided that $\gamma<1$, the modified inequality can be easily proved by using Gerschgorin discs. Note that if an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ lies inside the Gerschgorin disc for row $i$, then
$$
(1-\gamma)a_{ii}\le
a_{ii}-\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\le \lambda\le a_{ii}+\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|
\le(1+\gamma)a_{ii}.
$$
Therefore $\lambda_\max\le(1+\gamma)\max_ia_{ii}$ and $\lambda_\min\ge(1-\gamma)\min_ia_{ii}$. Now the result follows.

Comment: thank you  for your reply , i had a typo in my question so i edited the question now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the $a_{ii}$ are complex, by Gershgorin's circle theorem, we have for $\lambda_n \in B_i$, where $B_i:=B(a_{ii},R_i), R_i\leq \gamma |a_{ii}|$
$$|a_{ii}| \leq |a_{ii}-\lambda_n| + \lambda_n \leq \gamma |a_{ii}| + \lambda_n $$

For $\lambda_1 \in B_j$  $$|\lambda_1 - a_{jj}| \leq R_j \implies |\lambda_1 - |a_{jj}|| \leq R_j \implies \lambda_1 - |a_{jj}| \leq R_j$$